# Unable to add a content list to my action

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm trying to add a scene with a content list following this documentation `https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection#creating_a_list`, but when I try to invoke the scene I achieve this error: `SlotRequested Failed to create event. ErrorId: 8e964c04-0f07-40ce-ba60-5497385796bd`.

[This is the configuration of the slot filling into the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g48xF.png)

Here the response returned by the webhook:

```
{
  "responseJson": {
    "prompt": {
      "override": false,
      "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "Questa è una prova, scegli uno di questi tre:"
      },
      "content": {
        "list": {
          "title": "Alternative trovate:",
          "items": [
            {
              "key": "Prova1"
            },
            {
              "key": "Prova2"
            },
            {
              "key": "Prova3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "lastSimple": {
        "speech": "Preferisci il primo, il secondo o il terzo?"
      },
      "suggestions": []
    },
    "scene": {
      "name": "chooseAlternativeDealers",
      "slotFillingStatus": "COLLECTING",
      "slots": {
        "dealer_options": {
          "mode": "REQUIRED",
          "status": "SLOT_UNSPECIFIED",
          "updated": false
        }
      }
    },
    "session": {
      "id": "ABwppHHy6xRy_5IK0uOf9pplFJgbbJkT6qSs_HioKvJ7bxuXIpwPvO3qONuforo1SWISquCM_D9UNs6GYCw",
      "params": {
        "ALTERNATIVES_EXIT_CODE": 0
      },
      "typeOverrides": [
        {
          "name": "dealer_options",
          "mode": "TYPE_REPLACE",
          "synonym": {
            "entries": [
              {
                "name": "Prova1",
                "synonyms": [
                  "Il primo"
                ],
                "display": {
                  "title": "Prova1",
                  "description": "desc1",
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "Prova2",
                "synonyms": [
                  "Il secondo"
                ],
                "display": {
                  "title": "Prova2",
                  "description": "desc2",
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "Prova3",
                "synonyms": [
                  "Il terzo"
                ],
                "display": {
                  "title": "Prova3",
                  "description": "desc3",
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": ""
    },
    "user": {
      "locale": "it-IT",
      "params": {},
      "accountLinkingStatus": "ACCOUNT_LINKING_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED",
      "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
      "lastSeenTime": "2020-11-01T19:31:11Z",
      "packageEntitlements": []
    },
    "home": {
      "params": {}
    },
    "device": {
      "capabilities": [
        "SPEECH",
        "RICH_RESPONSE",
        "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the log of that event (slotRequested) which throws the error:

```
Failed to create event. ErrorId: d52e7c20-3bd6-4106-a03a-d840aef86b2b.
{
  "slotRequested": {},
  "responses": [
    {
      "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "Questa è una prova, scegli uno di questi tre:",
        "text": "Questa è una prova, scegli uno di questi tre:"
      },
      "content": {
        "list": {
          "title": "Alternative trovate:",
          "items": [
            {
              "key": "Prova1"
            },
            {
              "key": "Prova2"
            },
            {
              "key": "Prova3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "lastSimple": {
        "speech": "Preferisci il primo, il secondo o il terzo?",
        "text": "Preferisci il primo, il secondo o il terzo?"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

------ EDIT AFTER SEVERAL TRIES ------

Trying to solve the problem, I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706038/how-to-render-a-list-returned-from-a-webhook) and at the moment I don't have anymore the error `SlotRequested Failed to create event. ErrorId: 8e964c04-0f07-40ce-ba60-5497385796bd` but the list is not rendered. Now if I choose one of the possible choices, the slot (overridden by code) is rightly matched, so the problem seems to be only on list rendering.

Comment: What is it showing when it shows the list?

Comment: Nothing. I see the firstSimple and then the lastSimple message