# How to render a list returned from a webhook

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I am using Google Actions.  I am returning JSON from my webhook and receiving the following error when I test my action in the simulator:

> "Failed to render List or Collection prompt because of missing Type Override for a slot. Note, List and Collection should only be used in slot filling. There should be a corresponding Type Override that describes how to render the List or Collection for this Type."

The JSON is a slightly modified sample taken from docs at https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection.

The typeOverrides name 'items' matches a slot name for the scene.

Here is the webhook request and the response JSON.

*** REQUEST ***

```
 {
  "handler": {
    "name": "aa"
  },
  "intent": {
    "name": "searchIntent",
    "params": {
      "searchParm": {
        "original": "milk",
        "resolved": "milk"
      }
    },
    "query": "milk"
  },
  "scene": {
    "name": "Start",
    "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
    "slots": {},
    "next": {
      "name": "SearchScene"
    }
  },
  "session": {
    "id": "ABwppHGln0UTzfUPqJ1SMr1Cuw2TyPjJQoGUkULazcObus3vUwJCJCpba--5PSRwjqMQelRqMAUnwPvl",
    "params": {},
    "typeOverrides": [],
    "languageCode": ""
  },
  "user": {
    "locale": "en-AU",
    "params": {},
    "accountLinkingStatus": "ACCOUNT_LINKING_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED",
    "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
    "packageEntitlements": [],
    "lastSeenTime": "2020-11-05T21:24:16Z"
  },
  "home": {
    "params": {}
  },
  "device": {
    "capabilities": [
      "SPEECH",
      "RICH_RESPONSE",
      "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"
    ]
  }
}
```

*** RESPONSE ***

```
{
  "session": {
    "id": "ABwppHGln0UTzfUPqJ1SMr1Cuw2TyPjJQoGUkULazcObus3vUwJCJCpba--5PSRwjqMQelRqMAUnwPvl",
    "params": {},
    "typeOverrides": [
      {
        "name": "items",
        "synonym": {
          "entries": [
            {
              "name": "ITEM_1",
              "synonyms": [
                "Item 1",
                "First item"
              ],
              "display": {
                "title": "Item #1",
                "description": "Description of Item #1",
                "image": {
                  "alt": "Google Assistant logo",
                  "height": 0,
                  "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png",
                  "width": 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "ITEM_2",
              "synonyms": [
                "Item 2",
                "Second item"
              ],
              "display": {
                "title": "Item #2",
                "description": "Description of Item #2",
                "image": {
                  "alt": "Google Assistant logo",
                  "height": 0,
                  "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png",
                  "width": 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "ITEM_3",
              "synonyms": [
                "Item 3",
                "Third item"
              ],
              "display": {
                "title": "Item #3",
                "description": "Description of Item #3",
                "image": {
                  "alt": "Google Assistant logo",
                  "height": 0,
                  "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png",
                  "width": 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "ITEM_4",
              "synonyms": [
                "Item 4",
                "Fourth item"
              ],
              "display": {
                "title": "Item #4",
                "description": "Description of Item #4",
                "image": {
                  "alt": "Google Assistant logo",
                  "height": 0,
                  "url": "https://developers.google.com/assistant/assistant_96.png",
                  "width": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "typeOverrideMode": "TYPE_REPLACE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "prompt": {
    "override": false,
    "content": {
      "list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "ITEM_1"
          },
          {
            "key": "ITEM_2"
          },
          {
            "key": "ITEM_3"
          },
          {
            "key": "ITEM_4"
          }
        ],
        "subtitle": "List subtitle",
        "title": "List title"
      }
    },
    "firstSimple": {
      "speech": "This is a list.",
      "text": "This is a list."
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Slot Details]

Comment: I ran into this problem a long while ago and haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. Have you figured it out? If I figure it out before you I can come back and let you know what helped me.

Comment: I have given up on it.  I send back my options as a single text string, "item 1: ..., item 2: ...".

Answer (score 2):

I share with all of you the solution for this.

It is true that the documentation omits certain parts to make this work, but if we pay attention to reading and following it to the letter it really works.

Once we have our Actions Builder project, the first thing we do is create an entity in the types section. Just that, we don't need to add inputs or values, just create the type.

[image]

The next step is to prepare the scene where we will show our collection. In this case I created one called INTRO.

This is where you have the error. You are trying to display the collection in the webhook that fires when you enter the scene. Nothing has to be placed there, it must be empty.

[image]

The next step is to add the slot type and a name. We must also configure 2 more things, one is to make said slot mandatory and the other is to activate the checkbox so that it calls our handler who is in charge of painting the collection.

[image]

If you notice, I named the slot: **type_option** and it is of type **prompt_type**, that is, the type I declared in the first step. Then I marked that slot as required and finally I activated it to call the handler named **LaunchRequest** that is in my webhook.

Now let's see the code.

```js
const LaunchRequestHandler = app => {

  app.handle('LaunchRequest', conv => {
    conv.session.typeOverrides = [
      {
        name: 'prompt_option', // We reference the type of slot, not the name
        mode: 'TYPE_REPLACE',
        synonym: {
          entries: [
            {
              name: 'ITEM_1',
              synonyms: ['Item 1', 'First item'],
              display: {
                title: 'Element 1',
                description: 'This is the element 1',
                image: new Image({
                  url: '<YOUR URL>',
                  alt: 'example'
                })
              }
            },
            {
              name: 'ITEM_2',
              synonyms: ['Item 2', 'Second item'],
              display: {
                title: 'Element 2',
                description: 'This is the element 2',
                image: new Image({
                  url: '<YOUR URL>',
                  alt: 'example 2'
                })
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ];

    const items = [{ key: 'ITEM_1' }, { key: 'ITEM_2' }]

    conv.add(new Collection({ title: '<YOUR TITLE>', subtitle: '<YOUR SUBTITLE>', items }))
  })
}
```

This is the piece of code that we configure to be called when we want to present the collection. If we look closely, we refer to the type not to the name of the slot.

With this, everything should work, if we do the test from the simulator. Everything is perfect.

[image]

I hope my help has served you well.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, nice of you to post.   Unfortunately it may be a while before I can get back to this project and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Carlos!  I was wondering if there is a typo, "If you notice, I named the slot: type_option and it is of type prompt_type".  I think you mean it is of type prompt_option?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeOverride *name* should match the **Type** of the slot, not the *name* of the slot.

Comment: Tried that, same result.  It's a bit confusing as to whether it should be a type name or a slot name.

Comment: Same error? Can you update your question iwth a screen shot showing the Scene this is triggered from and the details of the Slot and Type in question?